# How do I add a Modern SharePoint List to a page

Tags: sharepoint-online

For about a year now I have been working on a SharePoint site.  I Wanted the security and features of hosting on SharePoint but I wanted to design the site myself instead of using Modern pages.  For the most part everything has worked out nicely. One thing I a trying to do right now is add a list to a page and allow convenient filtering.  When looking at that list through the site contents there is a nice simple to use format for filtering but when I add my list as a web part on a page it seems to appear as a classic SharePoint list.  Aside from the appearance not being as clean, it also is lacking in features and speed.  For example, it seems that I cannot add a "clear filters" button even though there is an apply filters button and if any filter change is made the entire page is reloaded.

Basically I just want to find a way to use the Modern SharePoint List and its filtering features from within a site page.  As of now it seems like I can only see this filtering option within the Administrative pages.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a site page and add the list as web part in site page, the list will be displayed in modern experience.

Use the List web part for your reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537

Comment: Thank you,  I realized I was doing this but I had CSS that was making it look different than the modern list normally would look.  The one thing I am still unsure about is if there is a way to have the right side bar menu shows up with all the filter check boxes.  For me it seems I can only filter from the column headers just like a table in Excel. When looking at my list from Site Contents though there is a really nice and quick filtering option that does not seem to show up when I put the list web part on a site page.  Any thoughts?